# Kernel Density Estimation - CrimeStat - lat lon mismatch

Tags: coordinates, kernel-density, crimestat

I currently conduct kernel density estimation for a point dataset. For the KDE in addition a reference file is needed, where the coordinates of the lower left and upper right are specified.

The coordinates of my point file are in WGS84, specified with longitude and latitude in the primary file setup. For the reference file, I added the coordinates of the lower left and upper right (longitude for x, latitude for y, as indicated in the documentation).

When I run the routine, I get the following error message:
Irrecoverable error: longtitude/latitude mismatch

The coordinates are specified twice in the same way for the primary and reference file and I already tried different combinations. I also did the method in CrimeStat version 3.3 in order to check bugs of the new version 4.02.

Has anyone a hint?

Answer (score 1):

you probably managed since you posted your question but just in case : it's probably not a problem of mixing latitude and longitude but an error in the coordinate system definition. you must have checked the wrong type.